# Python to eliminate rows whose nth column doesn't exist in mth column of another file

Tags: python, csv

I have two tab-delimited txt files with UTF-8 without BOM.

1.txt

```
A    B    C
X    x    y
T    d    2
```

2.txt

```
2   A
3   Y
2   X
```

The command

python eliminate_rows_in.py 2.txt 2 1.txt 1 output.txt

will mean: If some element of 2nd column of 2.txt doesn't exist in 1st column of 1.txt, eliminate the row of that element.

So that output.txt will be

2.txt

```
2   A
2   X
```

I have been doing this by sorting these files in respective columns in Excel, but then the file soon became too big.

Honestly I am a complete novice to python so the codes I can see I need are these 'structural' parts.

```
import codecs
import sys
input_file = sys.argv[1]
input_column = sys.argv[2]
match_file = sys.argv[3]
match_column = sys.argv[4]
output_file = sys.argv[5]

ifile = codecs.open(input_file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode="rb")
ofile = codecs.open(output_file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode="wb")

for line in ifile:
????????
ofile.write(line)

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

============================================

martineau's first solution produces

```
2   A

2   X
```

rather than

```
2   A
2   X
```

Can it be fixed?

Comment: you might want to check out argparse and csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the`csv`module to read and write the files, but that's not really necessary  in this case because it's relatively simple to do it yourself. Note that indices of lines and values (columns) on a line are zero-based in Python, so the first column corresponds to column number`0`, second to`1`, etc. Same thing for lines.

```
import codecs
import sys

input_file_name    = sys.argv[1]
input_column_index = int(sys.argv[2]) - 1
match_file_name    = sys.argv[3]
match_column_index = int(sys.argv[4]) - 1
output_file_name   = sys.argv[5]

# create a set of all unique values in the match_column of match_file_name
matching_values = set()
with codecs.open(match_file_name, encoding='utf-8', mode="rb") as match_file:
    for cols in (line.split() for line in match_file):
        matching_values.add(cols[match_column_index])

with codecs.open(output_file_name, encoding='utf-8', mode="wb") as output_file:
    # copy lines from input_file to output file whose value in the input_column
    # is one of the ones in the match column of the match_file
    with codecs.open(input_file_name, encoding='utf-8', mode="rb") as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            cols = line.split()
            if cols[input_column_index] in matching_values:
                output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution simply leaves a blank row where the eliminated row originally existed. I edited my question to clarify what I mean. Can this be fixed?

Comment: The blank lines were there because the code was adding an unnecessary newline to the rows that weren't eliminated -- but my last edit should fix that. I also reordered the execution of things a little bit to be more logical.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started.  It's incomplete, but hopefully it can guide you in the right direction.

```
import csv

# set stores only unique values to add items use .add(item)
first_column_items = set()
# load 1st column of 1.txt items into first_column_items 
# open 2.txt as infile_two

with open("outfile.txt", "wb") as out_f:
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)
    desired_column_idx = 1 # indexes are zero start
    for row in infile_two:
        column_value = row[desired_column_idx]
        if column_value in first_column_items:
            outfile.writerow(row)
```